Why is consciousness taken to undeniably exist?
Philosophers like Descartes famously claimed that the only thing one can be certain of is their own consciousness, encapsulated in the phrase “I think, therefore I am” (cogito, ergo sum).
However, doesn’t this certainty already presuppose the existence of consciousness, potentially making the argument circular? For instance, what exactly is the “I” or “you” being referred to here? Does this line of reasoning hinge on specific definitions of "existence" and "consciousness"?
I’m curious whether any philosophers have addressed this potential circularity or critiqued the cogito from this perspective.

The more Technically correct sentence is, "I think therefore 'I' is". All the Religions that aim for Enlightenment and Salvation are actually looking to dissociate "I" from "am". So when we usually say "I am", we are asserting "I" which is a result of thinking, Mind whereas "am" is the True, Existence. Consciousness just is, it is not a product of thinking. When you know "am", you understand Conscious, when you understand Conscious, you understand that everything else, the whole creation, is "ness".
The Real Problem is Wrapping Your Head around the fact that matter arose out of Conscious....

Descartes' claim that "the only thing one can be certain of is their own consciousness" is not an "argument".  It is a statement of fact, without supporting evidence. But every individual has their own evidence of this.

Consciousness is a direct experience. It is the fundamental empirical observation without which empirical observations are impossible. If you like, you can think of consciousness as the axiom we need to postulate prior to thinking or doing anything else.
'Self' — the notion of 'I' or 'you' — is a construct built on top of consciousness, a self-reflective set of identities that we associate with a mental object that we think of as ourselves. it's complicated…

If the self is just a construct, “who” is certain that consciousness exists?

@Syed: Consciousness is sure, though if you ask consciousness who it is, it will only smile indulgently. Ego's can question their own existence, because egos are fundamentally aware of the limitations of their own existence as constructs, and can get quite fretful over it.

+1 Indeed, it is as if consciousness is for the most part unconscious, and we just see the effects that bubble up to the surface.  However in discourse we have a to-and-fro of external signs.

You are right in assuming that "I" is having a conscious experience. In the original Latin it was "cogito", "I think". This formulation introduces a subject and object and thus plants the seed of dualism, aptly named after him, Cartesian dalism.
Hume, more than a century later, came with his bundle theory. The self, that is you, is a bundle of perceptions (in his terminology not only perceptions but also feelings and thinking). That's it. Just perceptions arising and disappearing. There is no I to observe. The "I" is the bundle.
Hume's bundle theory is remarkably close to modern cognitive theories. We have (or: there are) mental states, as we may call them, and they are so unalienably real (to us) that even Alex Rosenberg, sometimes endearingly called the 'mad dog of naturalism', doesn't deny its existence. And Alex Rosenberg has a pretty extreme eliminativist view on almost anything...
So, by eliminating the homunculus it is no longer I think, but rather thinking. Thinking can not deny its own existence.

Without an I, who is there to deny anything? “Thinking can deny” only makes sense if a subject exists, but as you pointed out, there seems to be no reason to believe in a subject

Yes, I know it is difficult. We are so conditioned by using personal pronouns that they restrict us in how we can perceive the world. We are in a sense natural born dualists, but this leads to all sorts of problems: if there is a tiny person in your head (the homunculus) watching the show that the brain creates, then there must be another homunculus in the head of the homunculus, et cetera, ad infinitum. Dennett called this feeling as if we are watching a show in our mind "The Cartesian Theatre"...

The argument is that identity is an emergent property. It is made up of smaller pieces that aren't yet identity -- emotions, senses, memories, and so on. A computer program is typically made up of smaller routines, each of which performs a specific kind of processing and none of which by itself can accomplish the full task. Likewise, it is argued that identity is nothing magical but is simply the monitoring process of you observing yourself. The fact that the monitor is running on the same hardware that is doing the other things is not a problem. There is no separable homunculus.

It's a large topic. Bruce Hood wrote a popular science book The Self Illusion: Why there is no 'you' inside your head. I think he's done a TED talk too. A good overview, I think.

@Philomath "There is no I to observe. The "I" is the bundle." A bundle is something, and it can be "observed", and it can also observe, in the case of mental bundles. There's no doubts that thoughts are many. The question is: why are they bundled into bundles of thoughts that find it hard to communicate with and understand one another. And the answer is biological: each organism creates its own mental space, separated from other organisms' mental spaces.

@Philomath Hence persons (human organisms) each have their own personnal mental space, and personnal pronouns tagging those.

@keshlam Good analogy. That sounds very much like what Dennett calls multiple drafts that have to compete for dominance..

Somehow I'm reminded of Escher's picture "Drawing Hands", only in this case one of them is trying to erase the other!

@ScottRowe Nice! Hofstadter was on to something with his 'strange loops'.

Indeed it is circular. As per Being & Time pages 362-363

if we are to obtain an ontologically clarified idea of Being in
general, must we not do so by first working out that understanding-of­
Being which belongs to Dasein? This understanding, however, is to be
grasped primordially only on the basis of a primordial Interpretation
of Dasein, in which we take the idea of existence as our clue. Does it
not then become altogether patent in the end that this problem of
fundamental ontology which we have broached, is one which moves in a
'circle'? . . .
We cannot ever 'avoid' a 'circular' proof in the existential analytic,
because such an analytic does not do any proving at all by the rules
of the 'logic of consistency'. What common sense wishes to eliminate
in avoiding the 'circle', on the supposition that it is measuring up
to the loftiest rigour of scientific investigation, is nothing less
than the basic structure of care. Because it is primordially
constituted by care, any Dasein is already ahead of itself. . . .
When one talks of the 'circle' in understanding, one expresses a
failure to recognize two things: (1) that understanding as such makes
up a basic kind of Dasein's Being, and (2) that this Being is
constituted as care. To deny the circle, to make a secret of it, or
even to want to overcome it, means finally to reinforce this failure.
We must rather endeavour to leap into the 'circle', primordially and
wholly, so that even at the start of the analysis of Dasein we make
sure that we have a full view of Dasein's circular Being.

Woohoo!
